# How can you get the word out of a vector using fasttext?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, fasttext

I'm using fasttext for word embeding as part of a transformer network, I supposed that if there is a function to get the vector of a word(get_word_vector()), there is a function to get the word out of a vector, problem is that I cant find it...
I get the response of my transformer as a vector but i cant finalize the process of getting the text...

someone know what can be done?

Comment: Using fasttext word embeddings in a transformer network is not a standard approach. So, to get help, I think you should share a minimal version of your code and some more details...

Comment: what is the standard approach